# Find number of Wednesdays (or other weekday) in a month - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I found this query for finding the number of Sundays in a month.
I have been tinkering with it but cannot figure out how to change it to get, say, the number of Wednesdays in a month, for example. Can you show me how?

```
    with 
months as (
        select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'),level-13) month
        from dual
    connect by level <= 36
  )
select to_char(month,'YYYY') year,
       to_char(month,'Month') month,
       to_char(month,'Day') first_day,
      to_char(last_day(month),'Day DD') last_day,
      4+
      case 
        when to_char(last_day(month),'DD') - decode(to_char(month,'D'),1,0,8 -to_char(month,'D')) >= 29
          then 1
        else 0
      end nb_sunday
   from months
```

Comment: I dont have idea neither, but here is a [**rextexter**](http://rextester.com/FVOCG15917) to test

Comment: How cool is that!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the game: You give me a year (like 2015) and a day of the week, in the form of a three-letter string (like 'Wed'). I will return a table with each month of that year and with the count of days-of-week equal to your input in each month.

Simply implementing here the suggestion from my Comment to MT0's Answer. I am hard-coding the year and the day-of-week (in a CTE) since "how to pass parameters to a query" (through bind variables and such) is not the focus in this thread.

```
with 
     inputs ( yr, day_of_week ) as (
       select 2015, 'Wed' from dual
     ),
     prep ( dec31 ) as (
       select to_date(to_char(yr - 1) || '-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from inputs
     )
select     to_char(add_months(dec31, level), 'Mon-yyyy')               as mth,
           ( next_day(add_months(dec31, level)    , day_of_week) -
             next_day(add_months(dec31, level - 1), day_of_week) ) / 7 as cnt
from       inputs cross join prep
connect by level <= 12;

MTH       CNT
-------- ----
Jan-2015    4
Feb-2015    4
Mar-2015    4
Apr-2015    5
May-2015    4
Jun-2015    4
Jul-2015    5
Aug-2015    4
Sep-2015    5
Oct-2015    4
Nov-2015    4
Dec-2015    5

12 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

The last wednesday of the month is given by:

```
TRUNC( NEXT_DAY( LAST_DAY( :month ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'WEDNESDAY' ) )
```

The first wednesday of the month is given by:

```
NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( :month, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'WEDNESDAY' )
```

Subtracting gives the number of days between them. Divide by 7 and add 1 and you get the number of Wednesdays:

```
SELECT ( TRUNC( NEXT_DAY( LAST_DAY( :month ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'WEDNESDAY' ) )
       - NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( :month, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'WEDNESDAY' )
       ) / 7 + 1
       AS number_of_wednesdays
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or you can just use the difference between the first Wednesday of the month and of the next month as suggested by @mathguy

```
SELECT ( NEXT_DAY(
           ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( :month, 'MM' ), 1 ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
           'WEDNESDAY'
         )
       - NEXT_DAY(
           TRUNC( :month, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
           'WEDNESDAY'
         )
       ) / 7
       AS number_of_wednesdays
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: It would be easier (and somehow more satisfying) to find the first Wednesday of "this" month, the first Wednesday of "next" month, take the difference and divide by 7. (More satisfying because both are found the same way). Or the same but with the last Wednesday of last month and of this month. Whichever is simpler.